# Question on Projectiles and momentum conservation

Tags: homework-and-exercises, momentum, projectile, kinematics

Firstly I apologize for bringing forth a high-school physics problem here, as some of you'll find this problem highly childish. But there are certain things i need to clarify about this.

Q:
An artillery gun is positioned on a horizontal ground and an artillery shell is fired from it so that the shell would land at a target, which is located at a distance 2000m from the gun. Suddenly the shell explodes into two pieces A and B at a certain point in it's trajectory. The mass of A is twice that of B, and both pieces land at the same moment, after travelling in the same vertical plane. If A lands at a distance 1800m im the direction of the target from the gun, find the distance to the landing point of B from the gun.

I don't need the exact answer , all I need is something to get the ball rolling! I tried this several times applying SUVAT in different directions and by conservation of linear momentum, but still can't approach a reasonable answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** The center of mass of pieces A and B moves in the same path as the intact shell would. (This arises from the conservation of momentum.)

Edit:

The gravitational force is only acting along the vertical direction. So there is net acceleration only in the vertical direction. Looking at the horizontal one, if we neglect things like air resistance (which we are neglecting), the net force along the horizontal is zero. If the net force on a system (along a direction) is zero, the change in momentum in that direction is zero. An explosion is an internal force in this case. Internal forces in the system cancel out, so there is no change in the position (or velocity) of the center of mass. This implies that the center of mass follows the exact same trajectory with or without the explosion.